# Finding the copper pipes the radiant floor heating converges

Tags: heating, central-heating, copper-tubing, radiant-heating

I'm trying to troubleshoot our central heating system in our residential house. Our house was built around the 90s and I've found that we use Radiant Floor Heating. The plans I've obtained from the public records are simply structural layouts and contain no plans for how the central heating was installed. I've asked and I've been told that the contractors just take care of that without really following an architectural or engineering plan.

So now I'm simply finding out the routing of the Radiant Heating System. I know on the floor, they run as PEX tube, so there's no way of detecting them. Unless we were to dismantle the flooring. The copper pipes, however are a different matter. I gather that an experienced contractor can predict where they are and they can even be detected by certain tools. Tools much like a stud finder.

So is it doable? Finding the copper pipes? What's the best way of doing it?

Also, I believe that the copper pipes usually run through the walls, is this true?

Comment: I have a building with underfloor heating - all the piping beyond the manifolds are nonmetallic and was laid to prepared plans. Connections between rooms occur in the floor slab. A good metal-pipe-detector ought to be able to locate copper piping near to the surface. I can't help feeling you would do better to describe the problem you are trying to fix.

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply. Will look into metal pipe detector immediately.

Comment: I'm about to buy a 3-in-1 detector http://www.blackanddecker.co.uk/en-gb/products/equipment/detectors/manual-detector--pipe--live-wires/bds200 . But the depth of detection for metals is only 2.5cm. Is there a code or standard that will ensure the copper pipes will be less than that depth for walls and flooring?

Comment: Why must you know? What is the problem you must solve that made you come ask thus question? It may simpler to address that....